# I was not able to open driver (chrome/firefox) in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, driver

solution that i found was -> 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='../drivers/chromedriver.exe')

**insert -- executable_path=''** it will solve the problem
as i was not able to comment on other posts, so i tried framing the question and share answers. 
Do let me know if anyone has any concern regarding this.

Comment: Are you asking a question or commenting on something?

Comment: If you are asking a question, we need a [repro].

Comment: this is an answer.@GregBurghardt

Comment: It is perfectly fine to answer your own question, but this needs to be a question. Then post an answer below it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to Download Driver of Your Preference if you want to Download Chrome Driver then You should Visit This Site - `https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads`

and Also Check Your Chrome Version So that You Can Download an Eligible Driver.

2. If you want to Download Firefox geeckodriver.exe then Visit -

`https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases` There in the Bottom You will Get the Download Link. According to Your Preferred Version Download One.

Now When You Downloaded Your Favorite Driver go to Your Editor of Python and Import all `Selenium` thing and Write the code you Wrote above and make Sure you Executed these Drivers where you will be Executing the file in Python Editor